# Does Rabbitmq support Elliptic Curve Encryption?

Tags: tls, openssl, android, ios, ecc

I am using rabbitmq for chat. I have already installed the ssl on machine, which work fine for Android platform, but iOS broker not able to establish connection with machine and always show SSL Handshake error. After doing some research i found that iOS required following Elliptic Curve Encryption

- Elliptic curve: secp256r1 (0x0017)
- Elliptic curve: secp384r1 (0x0018)
- Elliptic curve: secp521r1 (0x0019)

But didn't find whether rabbitmq support Elliptic Curve Encryption ?

Comment: RTFM (or ask RabbitMQ community).  I don't see how this question fits here, its about configuring a specific piece of software.